# How obfuscate python bytecode with Pyinstaller 3.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, obfuscation

I am trying to figure out how I can obfuscate python bytecode with new `PyInstaller`.

> c:\Anaconda32\envs\myenv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe
>   --distpath=./dist/win32 --workpath=./build/win32 --uac-admin --uac-uiaccess --key=MYKEY app.spec

However after building, I still hack the sources with `PyInstaller Exe Rebuilder` as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Use Cython to translate Python code into C++. Then compile the sources and distribute an executable. Although this may not work for some modules.

Comment: I've already used Cython for few modules in my app. Do you recommend use `Cython` for all modules? As Nautika works ?

Comment: If you want to obfuscate the code, you can encode it in `rot13` and then use `#coding: rot13` in the very beginning of each file.

Comment: You can use my obfuscator on the sources and then compile to bytecode any way you like. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Opy

Comment: using --key= does not help: pyinstaller will attach the key to the exe file to be able to decrypt the files for execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obfuscate a Python script in Unicode escape sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030487/obfuscate-a-python-script-in-unicode-escape-sequences)

Answer (score 10):

for more security you can use [pyarmor](https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/) and [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) lib

**use command:**

1. pip install pyarmor
2. pip install pyinstaller
3. pyarmor pack filename.py

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--key` flag from `pyinstaller`: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#encrypting

Comment: the op already used it