# Obfuscate a Python script in Unicode escape sequences

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I want to obfuscate a Python script by using Unicode escape sequences.

For example,

```
print("Hello World")
```

in Unicode escape sequences is:

```
\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x22\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x22\x29
```

From my command line, I can achieve this with:

```
$ python3 -c \x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x22\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x22\x29
Hello World
```

I've create a file and put the "Hello World" Unicode escape sequence in it as the source code.

But when I run it, I get:

```
$ python3 sample.py
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

How can I use Unicode escape sequences in my source code.

Comment: The problem is , python reads it as a string, so when you perform `exec(unicode)` or `os.system("python -c "+ unicode)`, I get the same error, because as it is a string, it adds "" to the unicode.

Comment: Your claim seems to be false: `$ python3 -c \x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x22\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x22\x29
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x70x72x69x6ex74x28x22x48x65x6cx6cx6fx20x57x6fx72x6cx64x22x29' is not defined`

Comment: In any case I don't understand your premise. `Hello World` **is already utf-8**.  Utf-8 is a superset of 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: I just tried `python3 -c \x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x22\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x22\x29` and it works. My python version is 3.4.0. I wanted to obfuscate the code

Comment: Where are you running that command? I believe we see different results simply because your shell is interpreting the escapes, and thus what the python interpreter actually see is just `-c print("Hello World")`, while my shell is ignoring the escapes. To test this try to run the "unicode version" of the command `import time;time.sleep(60)` and then check using `ps aux | grep python` which command line was used for that command, and you should see it without the escapes.

Comment: Currently I am using fish terminal on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PEP 263 header, which tells Python which encoding the source code is written in.

The format is:

```
# coding=<encoding name>
```

By using the `unicode_escape` codec (selected from https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html), Python will unescape your strings first.

**sample.py**

```
# coding=unicode_escape
\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x22\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x22\x29
```

**Result:**

```
$ python3 sample.py
Hello World
```

Comment: The above works for one liners. Suppose for the code `import os\n print(os.getcwd())` I get an error: `SyntaxError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes:  truncated \xXX escape`

Comment: The answer works for multiple lines. You're building your escape sequence incorrectly. You need to pad your hex values with a single 0. You need to do: `"".join(["\\x0%x" % ord(i) for i in my_code])`

Comment: For the mentioned two line code, I get error: `  9d0f240f3 SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with your solution. I was using `re.sub(r'\\xa$', '', ("\\x" + "\\x".join("{0:x}".format(ord(content)) for content in content)))` for converting code into unicode.

Comment: I screwed up my padding logic. It should read `"".join(["\\x%02x" % ord(i) for i in my_code])`

Comment: \xa is the culprit, but anyways your solution holds good for other untested cases. Thanks