# unicode way to write "hello world" in python

Tags: python

I came across this code, and I wondered how it works. Could someone explain how this works. And if you could, could you explain how to write this in a different way without the numbers? Thanks!

```py
# coding: unicode_escape

def hello():
  return \x27Hello, World!\x27
```

apparently, the comment is necessary. So if someone could explain it, and tell how to do it different without numbers, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: The unicode hex character code `x27` represents apostrophe (`'`). It's like writing `return 'Hello, world'`. The first line tells which encoding the file is written with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030487/obfuscate-a-python-script-in-unicode-escape-sequences

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. So now could you show me how to do this without the numbers or  strings or booleans? Thanks!