# .py to .exe but code obfuscated. how to convert it?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I wrote simple scrypt on python, obfuscated all main .py files with https://github.com/htr-tech/PyObfuscate. Now need to convert all this stuff to .exe

Problem is that now pyinstaller cant see imports of .py files and libraries at all. Before obfuscating i could easily convert this to .exe but now its not working. Is there solution to choose libraries and other .py files imports manually to create correctly working .exe file?

Python version is 3.10 if its needed

I tried pyinstaller default build config and auto-py-to-exe

Comment: You can try what's suggesting in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509064/9374673) using [pyarmor](https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/) with pyinstaller. Not sure how to do it with the library you're using.

Comment: Only a personal opinion, but everywhere I have seen obfuscation, problems soon arose, either on the developper side or on the client side. Copyright questions are *legal* questions and trying to solve them with technical ways is a pain in the ass for legal users, without preventing a determinate attacker to discover the code. Only 40 years of IT is the reason for my opinion...

Comment: @MihaiChelaru the problem with pyarmor is that i really dont wanna pay for full version, trial version is okay with my script but when it comes to libraries everything goes wrong since some of them are pretty heavy

Comment: @Grotrianv I appreciate the clarification. I didn't realize pyarmor is a limited free trial unless you pay for a license. Best of luck in getting an answer to your question!

Comment: There's no narrow, specific technical problem with a [mre] here; you aren't showing us the specific problem that happened when you tried, or how to recreate that problem to test proposed fixes. As such, I'm not sure this is an on-topic question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used cx-Freeze with custom setup.py where included all i needed, works fine for me